# easiest confirm box plugin with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code

```
<div id="delete">Delete</div>
```

My javascript code

```
$(function(){
$("#delete").click(function(){
var decision=decide("Do you really want to delete?");
});
});
function decide(str)
{
$("delete").after(str+'<button onclick="yes()">Yes</button><button onclick="no()">No</button>');
}
function yes(){return 1;}
function no(){return 0;}
```

Currently my yes and no are returning 0/1 but i want a return 0/1 from decide function depending upon no/yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous. You won't be able to assign it to your `decision` variable this way.

In other words: your `decide` function returns before the user clicks on any button, and will always return `undefined`.

Whatever you want to do with that Boolean, you'll have to do from within those `yes`/`no` functions.

---

Here's a quick sample of how to provide a callback:

```
$(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        decide("Do you really want to delete?", function(result) {            
            alert(result);
        });

        return false;
    });

    function decide(str, callback)
    {
        $('<div>'+str+'<button>Yes</button><button>No</button></div>')
            .insertAfter("#delete")

            .on('click', 'button', function() {
                var result = $(this).text() == 'Yes' ? true : false;
                console.log($(this).text(), result);

                callback(result);
            });
    }
});​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2Lf9/

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple use a jquery plug in?

Try Impromptu

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Comment: till now i have not used any jquery plug-in made by others as they are too big